# Oracle SQL Developer Case Expression nested query causing a "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" error

Tags: sql, oracle11g, nested, case

I'm trying to build a fairly straight-forward query that can be run by a monitoring platform. For purposes of this question, I need my query to return a 1 if alert criteria have been met and 0 if all is well. Here's a snippet of the query I have which WORKS properly:

```
select case when count(*)<1700 
THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' 
END CASE 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE date_value= '11-DEC-2015';
```

However, rather than hardcoding the 1700 value in my comparison, I'd like to do a nested query to pull the value form another table in the same database. When I re-write the query like so...:

```
SELECT case when count(*)<(select count(*) from Another_table) 
THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' 
END CASE 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE date_value= '11-DEC-2015';
```

...It returns the following at the start of my nested query:

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

I know there is probably a better way of doing this type of comparison or perhaps a something simple I'm overlooking but I'm still pretty new to Oracle SQL and would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to do this same type of nested query case expression. If I'm replacing an integer value with a nested query that also returns a single integer result, why do I get the above error?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: good catch; updated the title to Case expression rather than statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially get the counts from both the tables and then use those values for comparison.

```
select case when s_count < a_count then '1' else '0' end some_col
from (select 
      (select count(*) from another_table) a_count,
      (select count(*) from sometable where date_value= '11-DEC-2015') s_count
      from dual
     ) x
```

Another option would be to use the `count` window function.

```
select distinct
case when count(*) over() < (select count(*) from another_table) then '1' else '0' end
from sometable
where date_value= '11-DEC-2015'
```

Comment: Wow, this is why I love StackOverflow! I knew there was a better way to think about this problem, and your answer was just what I needed! Many thanks!